# likely permissions error when calling nodejs from php

Tags: php, node.js, permissions, file-permissions

We have a PHP file that calls a nodejs script to generate a pdf. The flow is like this:

- the PHP file generates an HTML file and puts it in the /tmp folder
- the nodejs file reads the html file and produces a pdf in the /tmp folder

This process was working when the nodejs file was in the web folder (/var/www/mysite), but we were told to move the nodejs stuff into the /opt folder. When that happened, things started to go wrong.

In both scenarios, the PHP produces the html file correctly. The PHP then runs this command:

```
nodejs /opt/puppeteer-pdf-generator/generate_pdf.js infile="file:///opt/puppeteer-pdf-generator/newReport.html" outfile="report.pdf"
```

The generate_pdf.js file has some console.logs inside it. The PHP outputs the *output* and *return value* from the exec() command. From this I can see that the generate_pdf starts to process things, but then the script stops after this const line:

```
console.log(1)
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ignoreHTTPSErrors: true, args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']});
console.log(2)
```

I see the "1", but I never see the "2". I'm not sure what's happening on that line.

As for permissions, the /opt/puppeteer-pdf-generator and everything under it are set to www-data:www-data and 775.

If I run the exact same command the PHP is running from the command line everything works, so I strongly suspect the issue might be a permissions issue. I'm not sure how to proceed in troubleshooting this.

Comment: Obvious question...why not just use PHP to make the pdf?

Comment: We tried several PDF libraries for PHP but they all had various layout issues. The PDF is intended to be printed so the layout was critical. In addition, there may be other systems producing HTML that we want to generate PDFs from that may not use PHP. We wanted to have 1 common system (nodejs) that could generate all the PDFs.

Comment: Ok. So it might make more sense to call the nodeJS via a http request perhaps? That's how node was intended to be used. Might be more reliable. And makes sense if you want to have lots of applications being able to use the service.